# how to update an RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have and an RDD[(Int,Array[Double],Double, Double)].

```
val full_data = rdd.map(row => {
        val label = row._1
        val feature = row._2.map(_.toDouble)
        val QD = k_function(feature)
        val alpha = 0.0
        (label,feature,QD,alpha)
    })
```

Now I want to update the value of alpha in each record (say 10)

```
var tmp = full_data.map( x=> {
      x._4 = 10
    })
```

I got the error

```
Error: reassignment to val
         x._4 = 10
```

I have changed the all the val to var but still, the error occurs. How to update the value of alpha. and I would like to know how to update the full row or a specific row in an RDD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RDD`'s are `immutable` in nature. They are made so for easy `caching`, `sharing` and `replicating`. Its always safe to copy than to mutate in a multi-threaded system like spark for `fault tolerance` and `correctness` in processing. Recreation of immutable data is much easier than mutable data.

`Transformation` is like `copying` the `RDD` data to another `RDD` every variables are treated as `val` i.e. they are `immutable` so if you are looking to replace the last double with 10, you can do is

```
var tmp = full_data.map( x=> {
      (x._1, x._2, x._3, 10)
    })
```